# Angular : $stateParams getting same object 2 times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button to open a modal.
This modal is opening twice (overlaying the other) and I can't figure out why.
Maybe this is a very simple problem, but i'm new to angular.
I realized that the `$stateParams` variable  is getting the object 2 times instead of 1 . here the console.log output :

```
Object { page: "1", sort: "id,asc", search: null, month: "", ope: "", codeAr: "", reIsus: Array[1] }
Object { page: "1", sort: "id,asc", search: null, month: "2016/12", ope: "", codeAr: "", reIsus: Array[1] }
```

The item in `array[1]` is the same in both line
and

```
        .state('validate', {
        url: '/validate',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_USER']
        },
        params: {
            reIsus: {
                array: true
            }
        },
        onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            console.log($stateParams)
            if(!$stateParams.reIsus){
                $state.go('re-isu', null, { reload: 're-isu' });
            }
            else{
                $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/entities/re-isu/re-isu-validate-dialog.html',
                    controller: 'ReIsuValidateController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        reIsusToValidate: function() {
                            var tabIds = [];
                            $stateParams.reIsus.forEach(function(ri) {
                                if (ri.selected === true) {
                                    tabIds.push(ri);
                                }
                            });
                            return tabIds;
                        }
                    }
                }).result.then(function() {
                    $state.go('re-isu', null, { reload: 're-isu' });
                }, function() {
                    $state.go('^');
                });
            }
        }]
    })
```

My main view with the button to open the modal:

```
                                <tr ng-repeat="reIsu in vm.reIsus track by reIsu.id"><td><button type="submit" ng-click="vm.unitaryValidation(reIsu)"
                                class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" data-translate="entity.action.validate"></span>
                        </button>
```

Comment: Use ng-repeat="reIsu in vm.reIsus track by $index"

Comment: You are not getting 2 objects. You are getting it 2 times.
Check what calls the route.

Comment: sorry @Jeyenthaaran Nanjappan  i forgot to edit the title.
@Abhishekkumar  same issue with `track by $index`

Comment: Can you page the full code here ?